# Parabolicity, equivalent definitions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

How to prove an equivalence between the following two definitions of parabolic manifolds:

(1) A Riemannian manifold $M$ is called parabolic if for each compact subset $K\subset M$ and each $\epsilon >0$, there exists a smooth cut-off function $\phi \in C^{\infty}(M)$ with $0\leq \phi \leq1$, $\phi \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of K and $\parallel d\phi \parallel < \epsilon$.

And,

(2) A Riemannian manifold M is parabolic if we consider the sequence of harmonic functions $\{f_{i}\}$ defined on $B(R_{i})-B(R_{0})$ satisfying $\Delta f_{i} = 0$ on $B(R_{i})-B(R_{0})$ with boundary conditions:

$f_{i}=1$ on $\partial B(R_{0})$, $f_{i}=0$ on $\partial B(R_{i})$, then they converge to the constant function $f=1$ defined on $M-B(R_{0})$ as $R_{i}\to \infty$ for any fixed $R_{0}$.

Crossposted on [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860665/equivalent-definitions-of-parabolicity)